# Django models not getting updated

Tags: html, django, django-models, django-views

I have created a coupon system where each user has 500 as balance initially in the employee table. I want to decrease this balance by the amount provided by user through the html forms. Given below are my files:

Models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
import django
import datetime
# Create your models here.



class vendor(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=20, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class employee(models.Model):
    name = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    id = models.CharField(max_length=20, primary_key=True)
    balance = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class transaction(models.Model):
    vendor_id = models.ForeignKey(vendor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    emp_id = models.ForeignKey(employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    debit = models.IntegerField()
    credit = models.IntegerField()
    timestamp = models.DateField(("Date"), default=datetime.date.today)
```

views.py

```
def updatingBalance(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        ven_id = request.POST["groupOfDefaultRadios"]
        amount = request.POST["amt"]
        x = employee.objects.get(name = request.user)
        x.balance = x.balance - int(amount)
        v = vendor.objects.get(id=ven_id)
        w = employee.objects.get(id=x.id)
        transaction.objects.create(vendor_id = v, emp_id=w,debit=amount,credit=0)
        y = employee.objects.get(name = request.user)
        #print(y.balance)
        return render(request, 'profiles/userLogin.html', {'model':employee})
    return render(request, 'profiles/userLogin.html')
```

html form:

```
{% if model %}
    <h3>Balance amount is {{ model.balance }}</h3>
{% endif %}
    <h3>Select vendor to pay!</h3>
    <br>
<form method="POST" action="/profiles/userLogin/">
        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
              <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="defaultGroupExample1" name="groupOfDefaultRadios" value="1">
              <label class="custom-control-label" for="defaultGroupExample1">Vendor 1</label>
            </div>

            <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
              <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="defaultGroupExample2" name="groupOfDefaultRadios" value="2">
              <label class="custom-control-label" for="defaultGroupExample2">Vendor 2</label>
            </div> 
        <input type="" class="form-control" id="amount1" name="amt" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter amount">
        <br>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

    </form>
```

Where am I going wrong? How to refer to the employee model directly? I understand that x might not be referencing to the model correctly. Also, I need to show the balance on html. How can that be achieved?

Comment: You never `x.save()`.

Comment: Damn lol. Thanks. And any idea about displaying the balance in html? Currently it is showing 0 all the time.

Comment: you should pass `y` to the template, not `employee`.

Comment: Yeah, got it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this does not work is because you never `.save()` your `Employee` object. Furthermore you should redirect in case of a succesful POST request to implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def updatingBalance(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        ven_id = request.POST["groupOfDefaultRadios"]
        amount = request.POST["amt"]
        x = employee.objects.get(name=request.user)
        x.balance = x.balance - int(amount)
        x.save()
        v = vendor.objects.get(id=ven_id)
        w = employee.objects.get(id=x.id)
        transaction.objects.create(vendor_id=v, emp_id=w, debit=amount, credit=0)
        return redirect(updatingBalance)
    y = employee.objects.get(name = request.user)
    return render(request, 'profiles/userLogin.html', {'model': y})
```

That being said, I would strongly advise *not* to store the balance in the `Employee` model. It will generate a lot of trouble like *race conditions* to keep the balance *correctly* updated.

Instead you can make an annotation that calculates for the employee the balance with:

```
class EmployeeManager(models.Manager):

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().annotate(
            balance=Sum(F('transaction__credit')-F('transaction__debit'))
        )

class Employee(models.Model):
    name = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    id = models.CharField(max_length=20, primary_key=True)
    # no balance
    objects = EmployeeManager()
```

Here we will thus calculate an aggregate over the related `Transaction` objects.

In that case the view is thus:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def updatingBalance(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        ven_id = request.POST["groupOfDefaultRadios"]
        amount = request.POST["amt"]
        x = employee.objects.get(name=request.user)
        v = vendor.objects.get(id=ven_id)
        transaction.objects.create(vendor_id=v, emp_id=x, debit=amount, credit=0)
        return redirect(updatingBalance)

    y = employee.objects.get(name=request.user)
    return render(request, 'profiles/userLogin.html', {'model': y})
```

So we do not need to update a balance field, it is simply updated by adding a transaction.

> **Note**: normally a Django models, just like all classes in Python are given a name in *PerlCase*, not *snake_case*, so it should be: `Employee` instead of <s>`employee`</s>.

> **Note**: when you pass an object to the template, that is *not* a model, it is a model object. You thus might want to change the name of the variable from `'model'` to `'employee'`.